# how to connect to mysql database via mysql front end softwares

Tags: mysql, database, connection

How to access the MySQL Database of my website from MySQL front end softwares e.g. SQLyog. I added my network IP to the remote Database Access Hosts list of the server but still I can't connect to the database. Although I can access through PHPMyAdmin of CPanel but not from my machine via MySQL front end.

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: Yes I am getting an error (10060) saying that can't connect to the MySQL server

Comment: Check this Faq: http://faq.webyog.com/content/23/15/en/error-no-2003-can_t-connect.html

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Sounds like your MySQL database is not setup to accept remote hosts. Check with your web host to see if this is possible. If not you're stuck with using PHPMyAdmin or changing to another web host.

---

I use Sequel Pro, which is free and very easy to use. When you create a connection to a database, whether by command-line MySQL client or desktop software, you have to specify the following fields:

```
Hostname (e.g. www.myhost.com)
Username/Password
Database name (the name of the database on the host machine)
Port (usually default and you don't have to specify)
```

You can also connect to a MySQL database on the command-line using the MySQL client. The command is something like this:

`mysql -h <host_name> -D <database_name> -u <user_name> -p<password>`

You often want to supply some additional options, like --show-warnings and --verbose.

Comment: I tried this but still getting this bloody 10060 error

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and type following command

> mysql --host=IP -u username -p

If you are using any other front mysql GUI tools add your IP to cpanel Remote access list 
and use same settings as derived from above command